# Creating a Matcher<Stream> for jUnit

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

The following code is designed to allow more natural assertions about the size of a stream.

```
Matcher<Stream> hasCount(int count) {
    return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Stream>() {
        protected boolean matchesSafely(Stream stream, Description desc) {
            long streamCount = stream.count();
            if (streamCount == count) {
                return true;
            } else {
                desc.appendText("count ").appendValue(streamCount);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void describeTo(Description desc) {
            desc.appendText("count ").appendValue(count);
        }
    };
}
```

This allows assertions such as:

```
assertThat(getWidgetStream(), hasCount(52));
```

It works fine when the assertion passes but when it fails (e.g. `assertThat(Stream.empty(), hasCount(1));`) it returns the error 
"stream has already been operated upon or closed" rather than the expected description "expected: count <1> had: count <0>".

When I checked the source for TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher I found that `matchesSafely` is called from both `matches` and `describeMismatch`. So Hamcrest is assuming `matchesSafely` is idempotent which mine isn't.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: The Hamcrest [documentation](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) advises "When using Hamcrest, there is no guarantee as to how often `matches()` or `describeMismatch()` will be called, so the objects passed as actual arguments should not change when referenced. If you're testing a stream, a good practice is to collect the contents of the stream before matching. "

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've discovered is to store the result between invocations.

```
return new TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Stream>() {
    private Optional<Long> streamCount = Optional.empty();

    protected boolean matchesSafely(Stream stream, Description desc) {
        if (!streamCount.isPresent())
            streamCount = Optional.of(stream.count());
        if (streamCount.get() == count) {
            return true;
        } else {
            desc.appendText("has count ").appendValue(streamCount.get().intValue());
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

This works but is not particularly elegant.

Comment: As `mtachedSafely` is called a second time after `describedTo` to produce the decription for the `but: ...` part. It seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @SubOptimal yes I suspect this is the easiest solution but it seems like a bit of a gap in hamcrest to assume that `matchesSafely` can be called twice.

Comment: But looking at [IsCollectionContainingTest.java](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/test/java/org/hamcrest/core/IsCollectionContainingTest.java#L89) it seems this is the intended way.

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for that link - I think you're correct

Comment: I create an issue report on [JavaHamcrest #144](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/144) as this behavior should be either documented or changed to a single invocation of `matchesSafely`.

Comment: There is now a [comment in the Javadoc](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matcher.java#L15) that objects passed as reference to the `matches` methods should not change there state when methods are invoked on the reference.

Comment: @SubOptimal Ok that makes things clearer. But seems a shame really. Adding a collector to the assertion makes it much less readable.